# Is it compatible with PHP 7.2?

Tags: 7, commerce

We have a Drupal 7 site running Drupal Commerce. Our host has now informed us that they will be updating PHP from 5.6.3 to PHP 7.2.

Is Drupal Commerce for Drupal 7 compatible with PHP 7.2?
I have tested Drupal 7 with PHP 7.2 on another domain; for most of the part, it appears to work. However, I have not been able to test Commerce on PHP 7.2, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Compatible with PHP 7.2?

Yes, currently the only issue I see in the issue queue is:

[PHP 7.2 Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal()](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3035138)

You'll have to apply this patch yourself since it has not been committed.

Comment: Will review / commit today. : )

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reply :)